# symfony 1.4 action does not exist in prod not in dev

Tags: symfony-1.4, production-environment

I'm completely lost here... Everything works fine in my dev environnement, but, for some reason I have a 404 error "Action "xxx" does not exist when I'm trying to access a module in my prod env.

I don't even know where to search...

Everything is up to date on my server, in the corresponding actions.class file, the corresponding action does exist along with the template...

I've cleared the cache many times...

If someone has an idea, it will be much appreciated !!!

Thanks all

Comment: If you execute `./symfony app:routes [application]`, do you see a route to your action?

Comment: Yes the route exists....

Comment: Have you tried setting the last parameter in the `dispatch()` call in `web/index.php` to `true` (enables debugging). That way you should get a more detailed reason why the 404 is occurring.

Comment: Yes, it says that the action does not exist...

Comment: I removed the cache folder as suggested but now nothing in showing, I have a blank page...SO i put the cache back on the server but still a blank page...help !!!!

Comment: how do you clear the cache? You're not deleting the cache folder itself, are you? Just call `./symfony cc`, or delete the contents of the folder.
If you have blank page your either not in debug mode (see `web/index.php`) or you have a problem with your symfony/apache configuration.

Answer (score 1):

If it works fine with development environment than only one issue that is cache please remove cache folder manually and than try it.

Comment: OKay so I've removed the cache and nothing is now showing up so I placed it back again, did a symfony cc but now nothing is showing.... help !

Answer (score 1):

Try to put this code in de settings.yml on your application:

```
prod:   
 .settings:
   no_script_name:         false
```

and then clear the cache...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, route exists, everything works in dev environment, cache cleared, etc.

What I've not realized is that I had no .htaccess file so obviously the routing system didn't work with Apache.

I requested the help of a colleague and he immediately spotted the missing .htaccess file :-)